# How to Import a .pos file as a numpy array with mixed data types?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am rather new to Python and I am working with .pos files. They are not that common, but I can explain their structure.
There is a header with general information and then 15 different columns containing data.The first two columns contain the GPS time (the date the first column and the time in the second - standard format YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss.ms), then there are 3 columns containing coordinates or distances in meters and then other columns that are other measurements, always numbers. [Here](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard17/uploads/dronedeploy/original/2X/a/afefb7775983f8cc772092dceec85fcf186d27c7.png) can be found an example, mind only that my GPST (gps time) is as explained above.
As a matter of fact, there are three data types in this file, that are datetime, integer, and floating numbers.

I need to import this file in Python as an array. Apparently, Python can consider .pos file as a text file, so I have tried to to use the **loadtext()** command, specifying the different data types (datetime64, int, float). However, it gave me an error, saying that the date format could not be recognized. Then, I tried with the command **genfromtext()**, both specifying the data types and with *dtype=None*. In the first case I got empty columns for date and time and in the latter case I got the date and time as a *string*.

I would like the date and the time to be recognized as such and not as a string, as I will need it later on for further analyses. Does someone have an idea on how I could import this file correctly?

Please, just try to be clear because I am a neophyte programmer!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There can be several ways to read such a text file given the format you desire. Does it absolutely have to be numpy or can you also go with pandas and such libraries? And the example link you posted can't be accessed.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited the question, now the example should be accessible. No, it does not need to be a numpy array, but as far as I know they are the most flexible to then use the data. Moreover, I work with huge amount of data...But any advice is welcomed!

Comment: Ok that clears it out somewhat. Can you add a .pos file with relevant data to your question which I can use? It need not be an entire file, just a part of it should suffice.

Comment: @RickM. of course. I could not put a proper picture of the data because I am new to StackOverflow, I cannot put pictures in the post. I also still don't have GitHub, so maybe I can share it through a cloud? Thank you

Comment: Yeah sure, that should be fine

Comment: Hi @Elisa, so I tried using genfromtxt() and it doesn't really work as you'd expect it to. I'd suggest that you go on with using the `with open()` and working on the contents row by row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question, maybe it is useful to someone.

.pos file can be open using the Pandas package as follows:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_table(filepath, sep='\s+', parse_dates={'Timestamp': [0, 1]})
```

In my data, the first two columns are date and time, which is considered as such by the argument "*parse_dates={'Timestamp': [0, 1]}*"

Answer (score 0):

I converted the POS file into csv using a py script (I can share it with u) and then I used the Pandas package for data manipulation

Comment: please include a code example of how your solution would work

Comment: Look at this repository https://github.com/strangedin/convert-pos-file-to-csv and then after u got a csv file you can manipulate the data with Pandas

Comment: I understand, but someone shouldn't have to click another link to know the answer, consider adding an example to existing answer by editing it